# "unable to securely remove '/lib/modules/3.11.0-13-generic/build': Not a directory" while upgrading the kernel

Tags: dpkg

When I try to upgrade Chrome by running google-chrome-stable_curent_i386.deb or if I try to do it through software updater I get get a "package operation failed - The instalation or removal of a software package failed" error. These are the details:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 284394 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic (3.11.0-12.19) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic/include/config/yenta/ene/tune.h': Not a directory
Removing linux-headers-3.11.0-13-generic (3.11.0-13.20) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-3.11.0-13-generic (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/lib/modules/3.11.0-13-generic/build': Not a directory
Removing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic (3.11.0-13.20) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/usr/share/doc/linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic/changelog.Debian.gz': Not a directory
Removing linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic (3.11.0-13.20) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/lib/modules/3.11.0-13-generic/kernel/lib/ts_fsm.ko': Not a directory
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic
 linux-headers-3.11.0-13-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic
 linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic
Error in function:
```

I've tried the solution posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203543/linux-kernel-not-upgraded-from-ubuntu-12-04-to-12-10-cant-remove-old-kernel?rq=1) but it doesn't work. I've tried option 1 and I get this:

```
nasty@nasty-Vostro-A860:~$ sudo apt-get install 2vard
[sudo] password for nasty: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package 2vard
nasty@nasty-Vostro-A860:~$ sudo apt-get purge grub-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-24 linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  grub-common* grub-gfxpayload-lists* grub-pc* grub-pc-bin* grub2-common*
  linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic linux-headers-3.11.0-13-generic
  linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 9 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 178 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 284394 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic (3.11.0-12.19) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic/include/config/yenta/ene/tune.h': Not a directory
Removing linux-headers-3.11.0-13-generic (3.11.0-13.20) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-3.11.0-13-generic (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/lib/modules/3.11.0-13-generic/build': Not a directory
Removing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic (3.11.0-13.20) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/usr/share/doc/linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic/changelog.Debian.gz': Not a directory
Removing linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic (3.11.0-13.20) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/lib/modules/3.11.0-13-generic/kernel/lib/ts_fsm.ko': Not a directory
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic
 linux-headers-3.11.0-13-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic
 linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

nasty@nasty-Vostro-A860:~$ sudo apt-get install grub-pc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
grub-pc is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-24 linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic linux-headers-3.11.0-13-generic
  linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 161 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 284394 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic (3.11.0-12.19) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic/include/config/yenta/ene/tune.h': Not a directory
Removing linux-headers-3.11.0-13-generic (3.11.0-13.20) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-3.11.0-13-generic (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/lib/modules/3.11.0-13-generic/build': Not a directory
Removing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic (3.11.0-13.20) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/usr/share/doc/linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic/changelog.Debian.gz': Not a directory
Removing linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic (3.11.0-13.20) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/lib/modules/3.11.0-13-generic/kernel/lib/ts_fsm.ko': Not a directory
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic
 linux-headers-3.11.0-13-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic
 linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And I don't understand what to do at the second option.

---

Well now I cannot reinstall them......

```
nasty@nasty-Vostro-A860:~$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic linux-headers-3.11.0-13-generic linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package linux-headers-3.11.0-13-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'linux-headers-3.11.0-13-generic' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux Kernel not upgraded (from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10) - can't remove old kernels and can't install new apps](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203543/linux-kernel-not-upgraded-from-ubuntu-12-04-to-12-10-cant-remove-old-kernel?rq=1)

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy linux-headers-3.11.0-13-generic linux-headers-generic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of files that dpkg interprets that files should be directories and directories that appears to be files.

I would recommend reinstalling those package to assure that the file database is correctly set:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic linux-headers-3.11.0-13-generic linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic
```

BTW, be careful with removing grub related package, and install the `linux-generic` package.

Comment: I have managed to delete them like this:                                sudo rm -rf /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic
sudo rm -rf /lib/modules/3.11.0-13-generic
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/doc/linux-image-extra-3.11.0-13-generic sudo rm -rf /usr/share/doc/linux-image-3.11.0-13-generic        And the update/upgrade.....

Comment: @user289034 you should reinstall those files... your system may need them again.