# Broken Packages (No file found)

Tags: boot, apt, kernel, updates, dpkg

i have some broken packages, more specifically:

```
 linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-104-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-108-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-108-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-127-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-128-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-130-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-130-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-133-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-133-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-134-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-134-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-135-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-135-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-139-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-143-generic
```

When i tried to remove one of them, i got this error:

```
(Reading database ... 646975 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic (4.4.0-101.124) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-101-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-101-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-101-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-101-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-101-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-101-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-101-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-101-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_7UInLs/lib/modules/4.4.0-101-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_7UInLs/lib/modules/4.4.0-101-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-101-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-101-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-101-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-101-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-101-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-101-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-101-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-101-generic
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
/etc/default/grub: line 1: #: command not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic

$ ls -al /boot
total 185785
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     6144 Jul 11 13:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root     4096 May 20 11:39 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1249237 Oct 10  2017 abi-4.4.0-98-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   190580 Mar 26 16:02 config-4.4.0-145-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   190862 May  7 16:38 config-4.4.0-148-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   190517 Oct 10  2017 config-4.4.0-98-generic
drwx------  4 root root     4096 Jan  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     1024 Nov 12  2017 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 14356810 Jul 11 13:39 initrd.img-4.4.0-101-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 44454972 May 20 11:40 initrd.img-4.4.0-145-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 44451845 May 20 11:40 initrd.img-4.4.0-148-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 43512380 Nov 28  2018 initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic
drwx------  2 root root    12288 Nov  4  2017 lost+found
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  3906115 Mar 26 16:02 System.map-4.4.0-145-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3907764 May  7 16:38 System.map-4.4.0-148-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3887471 Oct 10  2017 System.map-4.4.0-98-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7188984 Mar 27 12:03 vmlinuz-4.4.0-145-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7196216 May 14 21:09 vmlinuz-4.4.0-148-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7103856 Oct 10  2017 vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7105784 Nov  5  2017 vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic.efi.signed

$ uname -a
Linux Server 4.4.0-98-generic #121-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 14:24:03 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

s$ lsb_release -r
Release:        16.04
```

Comment: Add to your question the output from `ls -al /boot`, `uname -a`, `lsb_release -r`. I think you might have [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/a/203808/29073), but it's weird that you have "grub: line 1: #: command not found" as that line should be "# If you change this file, [...]" and any line with a # shouldn't be seen as a command ... strange.

Comment: `sudo apt autoremove` will remove most of these packages automatically except for the 2 latest kernels (1 old kernel and the current kernel). If there are any kernels that autoremove doesn't remove then install Synaptic (`sudo apt install synaptic`) and select the *Installed (local or obsolete)* option in the left pane to show them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case everyone was wondering the fix was actually pretty simple, the grub file had a simple error on the first line, no idea how that got there, but if anybody else had this problem, hope this helps.